# What are the biggest possible number of equal values on this NxN box?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a nXn box(n>3),a number is written on every cell such that the sums along all rows and columns are the same.Not all numbers are the same.What is the biggest possible number of equal values in the box?

I found the correct answer,which is 
n(n-1) by imagining a 4x4 box and in the box,all cells except the diagonal ones are filled with the same number,eg:2.For the diagonal ones,they are filled with different number but its same with the other diagonal one,eg:3.

However,I want to know if there is other way to do it.

Comment: Just add 1 to each cell and you get a new response with higher values. It seems your question need some clarifications.